# Setting the result from Room LiveData to a textview

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have a two queries which return two long values. I am setting these two long values to be displayed in individual text views. Finally I have a third text view which displays the combined value of both longs. I am having a problem getting the combined total to show as its setting the value before the livedata is returned.

Below is a snippet of the code

```
 private void getData() {

    mViewModelReframing.totalWorkouts(pkUserId).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<ModelStatsTotalWorkouts>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<ModelStatsTotalWorkouts> modelStatsTotalWorkouts) {

            for (ModelStatsTotalWorkouts list : modelStatsTotalWorkouts) {
                totalReframeWorkouts = list.getTotalWorkouts();
            }

            if (totalReframeWorkouts == 0) {
                tvTotalReframes.setText(0 + getString(R.string.workouts_empty));
            } else {
                tvTotalReframes.setText("" + totalReframeWorkouts);
            }
            
        }
    });

    mViewModelCheckIn.totalWorkouts(pkUserId).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<ModelStatsTotalWorkouts>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<ModelStatsTotalWorkouts> tableCheckIns) {

            for (ModelStatsTotalWorkouts list : tableCheckIns) {
                totalCheckInWorkouts = list.getTotalWorkouts();
            }
            
            tvTotalCheckIns.setText("" + totalCheckInWorkouts);

            // Combine both longs together for a combined total.
            totalWorkouts = totalReframeWorkouts + totalCheckInWorkouts;
            tvTotalWorkouts.setText("" + totalWorkouts);
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a better way to write the logic to achieve the desired result without the issue of the livedata not being returned fast enough?

Comment: Can you tell me what types are totalReframeWorkouts and totalCheckInWorkouts? Do you have defined two viewmodels in your component?

Comment: Yes two view models as they are seperate things. The two variables you mentioned are just longs so just the total number of rows in the room db for each respective table

Comment: As long as the value of any LiveData is not set, its value is always `null`. So you should make sure that you actually have a value before setting the text: `if (tableCheckIns == null) return;` and `if (modelStatsTotalWorkouts == null) return;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use independent Reactive streams like this (LiveData, RxJava, etc) you are going to have race conditions.  You need to make explicit the dependencies for an action to happen - in this case your ability to update the UI in the way that you want had dependencies on BOTH APIs returning.  This is the RxJava equivalent of `zip`.  A few tips:

1. Consider using only a single Viewmodel for a view.  The viewmodel should really be preparing data for your view specificially.  In this case, it should really be that singular ViewModel that handles combining this data before passing it to your vew at all.
2. Barring that, since you've chosen LiveData here, you can do what you want by using a [MediatorLiveData](https://medium.com/@gauravgyal/combine-results-from-multiple-async-requests-90b6b45978f7).  Essentially, it acts as a composite stream source that depends on whichever other LiveData streams you add to it as described by that article.  In this way, you can explicitly wait for all the needed values to arrive before you try to update the UI.

Comment: Thats a helpful answer but im struggling to implement the method for the MediatorLiveData due to me using java an dit being written on Kotlin. Any chance you could help with that?

Comment: Glad I could help!  Would you mind marking the question answered?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question by using this method:

```
public LiveData<List<ModelStatsTotalWorkouts>> totalWorkoutsCombined(long userId) {
    LiveData liveData1 = database.getUsersDao().totalReframeWorkouts(userId);
    LiveData liveData2 = database.getUsersDao().totalCheckInWorkouts(userId);

    MediatorLiveData liveDataMerger = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    liveDataMerger.addSource(liveData1, value -> liveDataMerger.setValue(value));
    liveDataMerger.addSource(liveData2, value -> liveDataMerger.setValue(value));

    return liveDataMerger;
}
```